# Cant click any options in select multiple in IE only - Javascript issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the following select multiple. This allows me to select multiple options without having to hold ctrl or shift and left click:

```
<select type="text" class="form-inline input-xlarge" style="width: 285px" name="specialTypeInd" id="specialTypeInd" multiple>
    <option value="N">Nomination Only</option>
    <option value="I">International</option>
    <option value="NT">Non-Traditional</option>
    <option value="M">Minority</option>
    <option value="S">Study Abroad</option>
</select>
```

I am also using the following script that applys to this:

```
$("#specialTypeInd").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var scroll = this.scrollTop;

    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

    this.scrollTop = scroll;

    $(this).focus();
}).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

In IE (9 and 10 at least) I can not click on any options. I click any of the options and its like its clicking on the select box itself? Any help because I am clueless, there are no errors printing out in the console. This works in chrome and firefox.

Comment: I just tested this and it works in ie 9

Comment: Im sorry i forgot to put the script I am using.

Comment: I'm not sure what your script it meant to do, but I can see that the script is running, and I'm still not getting the problem you reported. Maybe it's something with your css class.

Comment: @connormoore Could you try to reproduce the issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: How would I reproduce the issue in jsfiddle when it seems to be browser specific. The script in chrome for example, allows me to simply left click on multiple options WITHOUT holding the ctrl key to select more than one at once. It doesnt work in IE.

Comment: @connormoore We will be able to test it in different browsers by ourselves :)

Comment: Run this in chrome then IE and youll see what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/1hyep6dq/

Comment: anybody have some help for me???